# React handleChange methods event.target.value vs. (event, newValue)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onchange

What is the difference between:

```js
const handleChange = (event) => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
};
```

and

```js
const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
};
```

? The first seems to work in some cases, and the second in others.

Comment: Can you include the cases where first and second works for respectively?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, since React event handles do not have a second parameter, there is no `newValue`, only the event object. Are you using a third party React component library?

Comment: You can see an example for the second from Material UI (https://mui.com/components/tabs/#full-width). They use the state hook in React.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want to tell you that you are just passing a function for events like `onChange` or `onClick`, right? So, this is simple. We can pass any parameters to a function based on our needs. For those events, we basically use the following syntaxes:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
};
```

Here handle change is just a normal function, so it is not required that you only have to pass `event` as your parameter. It can be anything that you require to process that function. For the above use case, you needed input value that's why you passed the event object as the first param. But, maybe sometimes you will need extra data to work with that function. For example, you have multiple inputs, like below. You can add such inputs by clicking plus icon. And we might be storing data in an array of objects `[{trait_type:'', value:''},{trait_type:'',value:''}]`, each array element represents a pair of those input. It will be efficient to use a change handler that accepts both (event and index) of input as params. [image: Attributes and values inputs]

What is the main point is you are just passing functions to those events, and you can pass 0 or more parameters. It is not the rule that you have to pass `Event` for all event handlers. Yeah, sometimes you might require an `Event` object to stop propagating the event. Hope this explanation will help you. Make changes as you needed and best suited for you. Thank you.